# understand and modify previous R code

Tags: r

I am new to R environment and would like the understand the code posted in another thread.

[Integrating over a PCHIP Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478393/integrating-over-a-pchip-function)

```
1 > library(pracma)
2 > xs <- linspace(0, pi, 10)
3 > ys <- sin(xs)
4 > pchipfun <- function(xi, yi) function(x) pchip(xi, yi, x)
5 > f <- pchipfun(xs, ys)
6 > integrate(f, 0, pi)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Line 5 is calling function in line 4, but this is not passing x value. So how does line 4 take x value?
2. In the above setup, I would like to modify such that if x is in between pi/6 & pi/4, the function should return 0 otherwise return calculated value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function `pchipfun()` returns a function (definition). The x value is needed during the call of the constructed function `f`. The function `integrate` is calling `f(x)` inside.

Comment: (1) I understand, integrate function is calling f(x), but in line 5 there is no x.

Comment: (2) How to modify the code?

Comment: `pchipfun <- function(xi, yi) function(x) { if (x<pi/6) return(0); if (x>pi/4) return(0); pchip(xi, yi, x) }` But why not simply restrict the integration: `integrate(f, pi/6, pi/4)` with the original function definitions?

Comment: Actually, I used it as reference code but I am not interesting in integration. I would like to plot the cuve but it is still giving me error as: In if (x < 100) return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: That would be another question. In your question above there is nothing about an error message. But the error message is clear: if `x` is a vector with more than one element then `(x < 100)` is a logical vector of same length. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789635/the-condition-has-length-1-and-only-the-first-element-will-be-used-what-chang

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, you can read about *Currying*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

For question 2, perhaps you can paste what you have tried first.